Laplace Transform of $(f(t))^2$
Say $\mathcal L(f(t))=F(s)$, then what is  $\mathcal L((f(t))^2)$ in terms of $F(s)$? I tried integrating by parts by taking $e^{-st}$ as the first function and $(f(t))^2$ as the second function, but the answer came out in terms of $\mathcal L(f(t)f'(t))$ which also I am not able to solve.
$$\mathcal L((f(t))^2)=\int_0^{\infty}(f(t))^2e^{-st}\mathrm dt$$
$$=\frac{{(f(t))^2}e^{-st}}{s}|_\infty^{0}+\frac2{s}\int_0^{\infty}f(t)f'(t)e^{-st}\mathrm dt$$
$$=\frac{(f(0))^2}{s}+\frac{2}{s}\int_0^{\infty}f(t)f'(t)e^{-st}\mathrm dt$$
Then, I tried IBP by taking $e^{-st}f(t)$ as the first function and $f(t)$ as the second function, but it became more complex and unsolvable. How do I proceed with this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

There cannot be a simple relation between just $L(f)$ and $L(f^2)$. One way to convince yourself of this is to imagine a function which is $\pm 1$ at any point. Then $f^2(t) \equiv 1$ and $L(f^2) = 1/s$. However any such function will give a different Laplace transform $L(f)$ so one cannot predict $L(f)$ from just $L(f^2)$.

@Winther, how does it justify that $\mathcal L(f^2)$ can't be predicted from $\mathcal L(f)$? Besides, the function you took as an example isn't a valid one as it can have 2 different values for one value of t.

I mean any function where $f(x)$ is either $f(x) = +1$ or $f(x) = -1$ at any point $x$. For example $f(x) = 1$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and $f(x) = -1$ for $x\in [1,2]$ and so on. If there are many different functions $f$ which share the same $L(f^2)$ then you cannot predict $L(f)$ from $L(f^2)$.

@Winther, okay I get your point. But what about the other way around, i.e., evaluating $\mathcal L(f^2)$ from $\mathcal L(f)$?

The result may be the convolution of $F$ with itself (due to the converse of the convolution theorem), but that's not always the case. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584241/laplace-transform-of-the-product-of-two-functions for instance.

Rakshith, @Abezhiko, Wikipedia gives a formula for product of two functions. It's a Bromwich integral on a vertical line in the region of convergence of one of the functions. I have used it before and that formula is right.
